# Що означає слово "путниця"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Натрапила на доволі цікаву назву фірми: ["Путниця"](https://opendatabot.com/c/32449217). Зазирнула у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/putnycja), однак такого слова не знайшла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Словнику русинської мови](http://slovo.sochka.com/index.php?letter=p) знаходжу:

> **ПУТНИЦЯ** - еклiптика.

В [Словнику іншомовних слів Мельничука](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53397/281896.html) знаходжу пояснення:

> **КЛІПТИКА** 
>   еклі́птика 
>   (від грец. εκλειπτική – затемнення)
>
> 1. Велике коло небесної сфери, по якому відбувається видимий річний рух Сонця, або коло, утворюване перерізом цієї сфери площиною земної орбіти.
> 2. Площина, в якій рухається Земля навколо Сонця.

Також для детальнішої інформації можна звернутися до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)